# Estimating hardware for hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have got 1TB of hive data.I want process the data within 2 hours...And the hadoop cluster will not grow because it doesn't have user interaction. How much RAM and cpu is required for each machine if I want to have 3 running machines

Answer (score 2):

This is dependent on the complexity of your process. A simple word count will surely complete before a complex data science algorithm. Your choice of implementation (e.g. Map-Reduce vs Spark) will also influence execution time.

For any given hardware specification, some processes may complete while others may miss the deadline. You won't get a complete answer without giving more details about your workload (and even then the answer will probably be a recommendation to run practical experiments with your particular process). However, I can say that when sizing a cluster, there are two resources I tend to reference:

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.2/bk_cluster-planning-guide/content/ch_hardware-recommendations.html

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-select-the-right-hardware-for-your-new-hadoop-cluster/

The cloudera blog in particular discussed different hardware requirement depending on whether your workload is storage intensive, compute intensive, etc.

Comment: Read to where? If you're not doing much processing it will probably come down to Disk IO. If you have 3 machines and 1TB data, then conceptually, each machine will need to read 1/3 of a TB each. If the machines each have enough total Disk IO to read that within the 2 hour deadline, you'll be ok with a simple read even with modest RAM and CPU. However if your disks aren't fast enough, it probably won't matter how good your RAM and CPU are.